# Flash Actionscript 3 Converting Sprite to Bitmap/BitmapData - Not showing up on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to convert a Sprite into a Bitmap (by first creating a BitMapData out of the Sprite), but no matter what I seem to do, the Bitmap doesn't seem to show up.

```
public class Platform 
{
    private var startingPointX:Number;
    private var startingPointY:Number;
    private var length:Number;
    private var platformLine:Sprite;
    private var color:uint;

    private var platformBitmap:Bitmap;
    private var platformBitmapData:BitmapData;

    public function Platform(stage:Stage, startX:Number, startY:Number, len:Number, theColor:uint) 
    {
        startingPointX = startX;
        startingPointY = startY;
        length = len;
        color = theColor;

        platformLine = new Sprite();
        platformLine.graphics.lineStyle(5, color);
        platformLine.graphics.moveTo(startingPointX, startingPointY);
        platformLine.graphics.lineTo(startingPointX + length, startingPointY);          
        platformBitmapData = new BitmapData(platformLine.width, platformLine.height);
        platformBitmapData.draw(platformLine);

        platformBitmap = new Bitmap(platformBitmapData);

        //stage.addChild(platformLine);
        stage.addChild(platformBitmap);
    }

}
```

Yes, I imported everything.  Everything runs without errors.

The Sprite itself (which I called platformLine above) is able to display (see the commented line above).  However, stage.addChild(platformBitmap) does not display anything on the stage.  Using the beginFill and endFill methods don't seem to change anything.

I checked various sites about converting Sprites into Bitmaps, and they all say to use the draw method of BitmapData to do so.

So my question is... why does platformBitmap end up being "blank" for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What most likely happens is something like the following:

You draw a line in platformLine starting at say coordinate (100, 100) and ending at (110, 100) with a thickness of 5px. platformLine.width and platform.height will be 10 and 5 respectively.

When you create a BitmapData with size 10, 5 and draw the platformLine, by default platformLine's origo will be drawn at pixel 0, 0 in the BitmapData. Since the line starts at (100, 100), you draw the blank parts of platformLine and thus nothing gets drawn. To fix this, you can specify a Matrix to the draw method:

```
 var platformLineBounds : Rectangle = platformLine.getBounds(platformLine);
 var m : Matrix = new Matrix();
 m.translate(-platformLineBounds.x, -platformLineBounds.y);
 platformBitmapData.draw(platformLine, m);
```

We basically find the rectangle which encapsulates all graphics in platformLine, and then define a Matrix so that the graphics top left corner will start to be drawn at (0, 0) in the BitmapData.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.draw()` will start capturing graphics from the registration point of `platformLine`. It will continue to capture graphics horizontally as far as the `width` you give the constructor of `BitmapData`, same applies vertically using the `height`.

Looking at your code, your `platformLine` is always at `0,0`. It seems that instead of moving the sprite itself to where you need it, that you're using `startX` and `startY` to begin drawing the graphics wherever you need within that sprite.

This is where you're running into a problem. What you potentially end up with here is a sprite whose graphics don't start until say 40 pixels away from its registration point. Those graphics are then 20 pixels by 20 pixels in this example, meaning the width and height you're giving to your `BitmapData` are also 20. You begin drawing graphics from the top-left of your sprite in a 20x20 area, but there are no actual graphics to draw until `40,40`. The result is a blank Bitmap.

To get around this, [`BitmapData.draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) has a parameter (it's 5th one) that accepts a `Rectangle`. This Rectangle can be used to define the area you want to copy graphics from on the sprite.